# IMPORTDATA function in Google Sheets error

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to use the IMPORTDATA function in Google Sheets to download stats from baseball-reference.com.

For example, if I want the Team Standard Batting table from:

https://www.baseball-reference.com/leagues/MLB/2020.shtml

I click on the "Share & more" > "Copy Link to Table to Clipboard" to get:

https://www.baseball-reference.com/leagues/MLB/2020.shtml#teams_standard_batting

Then, in A1 of my otherwise empty Google Sheet, I'm inputting:

=IMPORTDATA("https://www.baseball-reference.com/leagues/MLB/2020.shtml#teams_standard_batting")

however, I'm getting #REF with the following error message:

"Result was not automatically expanded, please insert more columns (86)."

Answer (score 1):

`IMPORTDATA` needs to be almost always restricted

try for starters:

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(IMPORTDATA("https://www.baseball-reference.com/leagues/MLB/2020.shtml#teams_standard_batting"); 5000; 20)
```

this will import you the source code of that site.

---

### update:

try:

```
=IMPORTHTML("https://www.baseball-reference.com/leagues/MLB/2020.shtml#teams_standard_batting", 
 "table", 1)
```

[image]

Comment: No #REF anymore but it's not importing the data from the table.  Getting the below now:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-version="klecko-" data-root="/home/br/build" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/WebSite" lang="en" class="no-js" >
<head>
<!-- Quantcast Choice. Consent Manager Tag v2.0 (for TCF 2.0) -->
<script type="text/javascript" async=true>
(function() {
var host = window.location.hostname;
var element = document.createElement('script');
var firstScript = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
var url = 'https://quantcast.mgr.consensu.org'

Comment: no luck there either, same error message appearing across the columns now instead of down the rows.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add another 86 columns, like the warning is telling you

Comment: You could explain why this warning is occurring (i.e., precisely why the additional 86 columns are needed).  I am a reviewer.  StackOverflow requested review of this answer due to you being a new user.  Your answer is much appreciated & helpful.  This comment is to help you take a good answer & make it excellent.